# Tinymce deletes <html> tags when output in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I have made a own litle cms with the tinymce. When inserting plain text in pre tags the code gets outputed the right way on the website but when i update the editor the html tags gets removed.

**Tinymce setup**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({

    selector: "textarea.editme",
   width : "60.5%",
   resize: false,
preformatted : true,
menubar:false,

});
</script>
```

**Tinymce Editor**

```
<textarea name="content"><?php echo $data['course_content'];?>  </textarea><br />
```

I echo out the content from the Database here but as I said the html tags gets deleted in the textarea.All other text is showed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the PHP FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS on all postvars. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please update the answer with an example nad don't forget to upvote the question so more people can enoy your knowledge. @Ome Ko